# Is there a way to compile this into a smaller segment of code?

Tags: discord.js

I am writing a discord bot to ping a user at a set interval. And I want to know if there is a way to compile this to not have to copy and paste the entire script to have the same thing happen for other users.

```
client.on('message', message => {
if(message.content === '&ping zach forever') {
setInterval(() => {
var yourchannel = client.channels.cache.get('704506336339034115');
yourchannel.send('<@UserID>');
}, "5000");
}});

client.on('message', message => {
if(message.content === '&ping maxx forever') {
setInterval(() => {
var yourchannel = client.channels.cache.get('704506336339034115');
yourchannel.send('<@UserID>');
}, "5000");
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with discord bots in particular, but as general JavaScript advice:

```
const users = ["zach", "maxx"];
client.on('message', message => {
    const splits = message.content.split(' ');
    if (splits.length === 3 && splits[0] === '&ping' && splits[2] === 'forever' && users.includes(splits[1])) {
        setInterval(() => {
            var yourchannel = client.channels.cache.get('704506336339034115');
            yourchannel.send('<@UserID>');
        }, "5000");
    }
});
```

Simply expand the users array with the required names. You can also modify the array at runtime with `.push()` and `.splice()`. If you'd like the bot to trigger even if there is text after the command, check for `splits.length >= 3` instead.

PS. As a general rule, using `var` is frowned upon these days. Use `const` for values only assigned once, and `let` otherwise.

Edit:
Here's a bit more fleshed out example, that includes hardcoded user ID's for each name, applies the duration (in seconds), and also includes a &stop command to stop pinging a certain person. (Code is not tested to run correctly, since I don't have a discord bot account, and don't want to make one either)

```
const users = new Map(Object.entries({
    "zach": "UserID1",
    "maxx": "UserID2"
}));
const active = new Map();
client.on('message', message => {
    const splits = message.content.split(' ');
    if (splits.length === 3 && splits[0] === '&ping' && users.has(splits[1])) {
        const channel = client.channels.cache.get('704506336339034115');
        const message = `<@${users.get(splits[1])}>`;
        const time = Number(splits[2]);
        if (isNaN(time) && splits[2] !== 'forever') {
            // Passed a time that wasn't a number - possibly send back an error message
        } else {
            const id = setInterval(() => channel.send(message), 5000);
            active.set(splits[1], id);
            if (!isNaN(time)) setTimeout(() => clearInterval(id), time * 1000);
        }
    }
    if (splits.length === 2 && splits[0] === '&stop') {
        const id = active.get(splits[1]);
        if (id) {
            clearInterval(id);
            active.delete(splits[1]);
        }
    }
});
```